# ConTeXt MarkIV: Pagenumber in layer not working

Tags: context, page-numbering, context-mkiv, metapost

I want to put pagenumber and navigation into a layer, but the counter for pagenumber is not working. Here's a minimal example:

```
\usemodule[graph]
\usesymbols[nav]
\setupsymbolset[navigation 1]
\setupinteraction[page=yes]

\setuppapersize[letter][letter]
\setuplayout[backspace=0.38\makeupwidth,leftmargin=0.3\makeupwidth,rightmargin=0pt,header=4em,footer=4em,top=0em,topspace=1em,topdistance=0em,bottom=0em,bottomspace=1em,bottomdistance=0em,width=34em,height=64em]

\startreusableMPgraphic{navegacionfondo}
path p,q ;
p := (0,0) -- (60mm,0) .. (65mm,5mm) .. (60mm,10mm) -- (0,10mm) ;
q := (0,1mm) -- (59mm,1mm) .. (64mm,5mm) .. (59mm,9mm) -- (0,9mm) ;
fill p--cycle withcolor red ;
draw q withcolor white withpen pencircle scaled .5pt dashed evenly ;
\stopreusableMPgraphic

\setupbuttons[state=start,frame=off]

\defineoverlay[fondonav][{\reuseMPgraphic{navegacionfondo}}]

\definelayer[navegacion][x=0mm,y=8mm,width=65mm,height=10mm,state=repeat]
\setlayer[navegacion][hoffset=30mm]{\framed[background=fondonav,frame=off]{\button{\color[white]{\symbol[previouspage]}}[PreviousPage]\hskip.5em\pagenumber\button{\color[white]{\hskip0.5em\symbol[nextpage]}}[NextPage]}}
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=navegacion]

\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth \page}
\stoptext
```

But pagenumber counter is not working: all pages are numbered as 1. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: Advice for further posts: You should create a *minimal* example. That means to remove any code that is not directly related to your problem. You could haved removed e.g. the modules, symbols, buttons, interaction and the entire MetaPost code. A simple `\pagenumber` within a `\setlayer` already demonstrates the problem. The entire example could have been compressed to six lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem and the solution is described in [ConTeXt wiki - Layers](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers#Use_dynamic_content).

> The content of layer is fixed after your set it and will appear in the same way on each page.
>   […]
>   To recalculate the content on each new page you have to enclose the `\setlayer` settings within `\startsetups ... \stopsetups`

Here is an example:

```
\definelayer
  [navegacion]

\startsetups [navegacion]
  \setlayer
    [navegacion]
    {\framed[offset=1cm]{\pagenumber}}
\stopsetups

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background=navegacion, setups=navegacion]

\starttext
  \dorecurse
    {10}
    {\input knuth \page}
\stoptext
```